# swift: only show section headers if more than 1 section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a table with a variable number of sections. If there are more than one section i want to show show custom Headers, but if there is only one, i don't want a header at all.
My Approach is to use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` and return `nil` if i have only one section. But instead of showing no header, i get an empty header. Any ideas?

here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Orders"

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self


    let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "SectionHeader", bundle: Bundle.main)
    tableView.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if(ordersList.count < 2) {return nil}
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SectionHeader") as! SectionHeader
    headerView.label.text = "\(sectionHeaders[section]) (\(ordersList[section].count))"
    headerView.button.setTitle(self.collapsed[section] ? "▶" : "▼", for: .normal)
    headerView.onTap = {
        self.collapsed[section] = !self.collapsed[section]
        headerView.button.rotate(self.collapsed[section] ? CGFloat(-.pi/2.0) : CGFloat(.pi/2.0), duration: 0.1, completion: {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .fade)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        })
    }

    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use heightForHeaderInSection delegate method also. Make height 0 if condition not satisfy. For Reference -

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if(ordersList.count < 2) {return 0.1}
    else { return HEIGHT} //custom value of view height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following methods to achieve the desired result:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if(ordersList.count < 2) {return nil}
        return ordersList.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if(ordersList.count < 2) {return nil} 
      //else return some view }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if(ordersList.count < 2) {return 0}
         return some_height

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView.numberOfSections` to get the *section count*. And use this value in `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` to check whether you want return `SectionHeader` or `nil`. You need to return `nil` in case you don't want to show `header` in a particular `section`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard tableView.numberOfSections > 1 else {
        return nil
    }
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SectionHeader") as! SectionHeader
    //add rest of the code...
    return headerView
}
```

Implement `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` to return the `header height` based on the `section`. Return `0` if you don't want to show `header` in a `section` otherwise it will take the `default header height`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return (tableView.numberOfSections > 1) ? 100.0 : 0.0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should override numberOfSections method of tableview. And you should not use dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView for section header view. Section header views should be a custom view.

-- numberOfSections

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionCount
}
```

-- sectionHeaderView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // you can store data on a view model
    let cellViewModel = viewModel.returnViewModel(index: section)

    switch cellViewModel.type {
    case .sampleViewModel1:
        return UIView() // sampleView1
    case .sampleViewModel2:
        return UIView() // sampleView2
    }
}
```